# XCode Core Data Not Loading Correctly in Some Scripts

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, count

I save data for my application with Coredata in a list called Homework. In one of my View Controller .swift files, I have this code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData


class HomeworkTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var homeworks = [Homework]()
    func get() {
        print(homeworks.count)
    }

    // trucated...
}
```

Which prints out `1`

However, in another view controller, I have this code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class HomeworkViewController: UINavigationController {
    
    var homeworks = [Homework]()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var theHomeworkTabBarItem: UITabBarItem!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        gameTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(plsReloadData), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        //theHomeworkTabBarItem.badgeValue = "test"
    }
    
    @objc func plsReloadData() {
        print(homeworks.count)
        if homeworks.count != 0 {
            theHomeworkTabBarItem.badgeValue = String(homeworks.count)
        } else {
            theHomeworkTabBarItem.badgeValue = nil
        }
        
    }

}
```

which prints out `0`.

Why aren't they the same?

Comment: Where in the code are you actually loading the values from core data?

Comment: That was my problem, I was never loading it in the second script. I added this in, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined 2 different variables which both happen to be named `homeworks`, and which point to the same kind of array.  For the `get()` to print 1, you must have put something into the `HomeworkTableViewController`  array but the one in `HomeworkViewController` is empty.

Comment: I made the variable names unique, and since it is saved in CoreData, wouldn't it be saved across each scripts, or do I need to update the homeworks variable everytime I change it?

Comment: A simple array only knows what you tell it.  If you'd like something that can be configured for automatic tracking of Core Data changes, have a look at NSFetchedResultsController.